# Is it possible to extract RGB from image in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a base64 encoded image taken with the RNCamera library for react-native..

Is there a way I can get an RGB array from the image I just got? I put it inside an  tag, can i extract the RGB from there?

```
  <RNCamera
      ref={ref => {
        this.camera = ref;
      }}
      captureAudio={false}
      style={styles.preview}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
      flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
      androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
        message: '-',
        title: '-',
        buttonPositive: '-',
        buttonNegative: '-',
      }}>
      {takenImageSrc && (
        <View>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: takenImageSrc,
            }}
          ></Image>
        </View>
      )}
    </RNCamera>
```

For example, I want to get from the RGB of the Image part

I already tried using a lot of libraries such as react-native-get-pixel, react-native-pixel-color, and more, and the only way I found is probably by using a backend..

Is it possible to do it using the app itself?

Comment: Probably. Do some research, have a go, and come back with a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited my question based on what I've already done, Thanks!

Comment: But you haven't added the crucial part. The [mcve].